# Sorting an ffdf (ff package) in R language

Tags: r, ff

I have a big file (size > 4GB) loaded into an ffdf. The file has a table structure where each line respects the pattern "string, \t, num, \t, num". 
How can I sort the ffdf by the first column? After the sorting I have to print the ffdf to another file.

Comment: I've try the function "ff::ffdfsort()" but the result is not fully ordered. It is composed by some ordered chunks.